# Sales SUM per country, state, city and district from five Mysql tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli

I have the five below tables, I want to show the sales SUM per country, state, city and district by using one mysql query if possible:

note: If there is no sales in the state, city, district, then I need the query result to show 0 or empty space (the state, city, district name has to be shown even if there is no sales for that specific state, city or district)

```
+------------+----------+
|  country              |
+------------+----------+
| country_id | country  |
+------------+----------+
| 1          | country1 |
| 2          | country2 |
+------------+----------+


+----------------+--------+------------+
| state_province                       |
+----------------+--------+------------+
| state_id       | state  | country_id |
+----------------+--------+------------+
| 1              | state1 | 1          |
| 2              | state1 | 2          |
| 3              | state2 | 2          |
| 4              | state2 | 1          |
+----------------+--------+------------+


+---------+-------+----------+
|  city                      |
+---------+-------+----------+
| city_id | city  | state_id |
+---------+-------+----------+
| 1       | city1 | 1        |
| 2       | city2 | 1        |
| 3       | city1 | 3        |
| 4       | city2 | 3        |
| 5       | city1 | 4        |
| 6       | city2 | 4        |
+---------+-------+----------+
```

please note that state (state_id =2) in country (country_id = 2) has no cities in the above table.

```
+-------------+-----------+---------+
|  district                         |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| district_id | district  | city_id |
+-------------+-----------+---------+
| 1           | district1 | 1       |
| 2           | district2 | 1       |
| 3           | district1 | 2       |
| 4           | district2 | 2       |
| 5           | district1 | 4       |
| 6           | district2 | 4       |
| 7           | district1 | 5       |
| 8           | district1 | 6       |
+-------------+-----------+---------+


+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
|  sales                                                            |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
| sales_id | country_id | state_id | city_id | district_id | amount |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
| 1        | 1          | 0        | 0       | 0           | 1000   |
| 2        | 1          | 0        | 0       | 0           | 2000   |
| 3        | 1          | 1        | 0       | 0           | 300    |
| 4        | 1          | 1        | 0       | 0           | 70     |
| 5        | 1          | 1        | 1       | 0           | 50     |
| 6        | 1          | 1        | 1       | 1           | 25     |
| 7        | 1          | 4        | 1       | 1           | 25     |
| 8        | 1          | 4        | 5       | 0           | 25     |
| 9        | 2          | 0        | 0       | 0           | 3000   |
| 10       | 2          | 0        | 0       | 0           | 500    |
| 11       | 2          | 3        | 0       | 0           | 300    |
| 12       | 2          | 3        | 4       | 6           | 70     |
+----------+------------+----------+---------+-------------+--------+
```

[Demo with my current attempt](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXehUWTE5jgKrVe4i4RbEE/0)

Thank you

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: your question  .. si not clear  .. show your expected . result  .. and as asked  by Strawberry  ..the query you have tried ..

Comment: Remember that SO is not a code writing service. We're glad to help you fix a problem with your code, but you have to at least show what you have tried, and what error or problem you can't get past.

Comment: I wonder why the question is not clear scaisEdge? I managed to show the results (the sales SUM) for the district table by using a query similar to the this: SELECT *, country.country_id, state.state_id, district.district_id, SUM(sales.amount) as the_sum
FROM district
JOIN sales ON sales.country_id =country.country_id 
AND sales.state_id=state.state_id
AND sales.city_id=city.city_id
AND sales.district_id=district.district_id
group by district_id
Order by state_id,city_id,district_id

Comment: based on query in your comment  have your some error  .. ?? .. or have you unexpcted result  .. if you have already tried  the query in your comment .. what's you exact  question .?  (PS  ... update you question and add  you  query code  too)   ..  .

Comment: Thank you Michał Turczyn, it is working

Comment: From the description of the `tsql` tag: "Do not use this tag for MySQL, PostgreSql, Oracle(Pl/SQL) related queries." It's also unclear what `php` and `mysqli` have to do with the question.

Comment: You'll want to switch from `inner join`s to `outer join`s to include rows that don't match other data, e.g. states with no cities.

Comment: @HABO You know you can just edit that tag out (as I did right now)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to group by three column (`city_id`, `state_id`, `district_id`), it's pointless, since it won't change anything in your `sales` table. There you have already partitoned information.

Moreover, in `sales` table you have 0 in place of some IDs and there isn't any ID equal to 0 in any table. You need to rethink what you really want I guess.

I think you just need simple JOIN:

```
SELECT country,
       state,
       city,
       district,
       coalesce(amount, 0) amount
FROM country ctr
JOIN state_province st ON ctr.country_id = st.country_id
JOIN city c ON c.state_id = st.state_id
LEFT JOIN district d ON d.city_id = c.city_id
LEFT JOIN sales s ON
    s.country_id = ctr.country_id AND
    s.state_id = st.state_id AND
    s.city_id = c.city_id AND
    s.district_id = d.district_id
```

[Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/nXehUWTE5jgKrVe4i4RbEE/1)